# Counting Rows/Columns of Selected Range Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to determine if a selected range is within a set area... This toggles Copy/Paste restrictions in the spreadsheet. I have figured it out, I think, but I'm getting a run-time error 6 (Overflow) if you select an entire row or column. This is what I've got..

```
Function BETWEENROWS(ByVal Selected As Range, ByVal Min As Double, ByVal Max As Double) As Boolean
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Selected.Row + Selected.Rows.Count - 1
    If BETWEEN(Min, Selected.Row, Max) = True And BETWEEN(Min, LastRow, Max) = True Then
        BETWEENROWS = True
    Else
        BETWEENROWS = False
    End If
End Function
```

There is one for columns `BETWEENCOLUMNS` as well and the function `BETWEEN` just returns True/False if a given number is between a min and max value.

This is working great, however, if an entire row/column is selected it's throwing an error and I'm not too familiar with VBA and the only way that I know of bypassing the error is with `On Error Resume Next` but that seems like I'm putting a bandaid on it and would like to figure out how to fix it another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your LastRow variable is not the correct type for a number as large as the max columns/rows of the spreadsheet. Change the type to Long:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an overflow error because you have made the `LastRow` variable an integer. Since there are more rows in an entire column then can fit in an integer variable, it triggers the overflow. You could fix this by changing the `LastRow` variable to be type `Long`

However, rather then comparing row values you may want to look into the `Intersect()` function. Given two (or more) ranges it will return the range object that represents the intersection of the two ranges. You could then check that intersection. If they don't intersect the range object will be `Nothing`. There is a good tutorial for this function at [ozgrid.com](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/vba-intersect.htm)

**UPDATE**
Here is the code to ensure range intersects fully using the `Intersect()` function

```
'// Run a test here to make sure Intersect does not return Nothing

If (TestRNG.Count <= ISectRNG.Count) And (Intersect(TestRNG, ISectRNG).Count = TestRNG.Count) Then  
    '// All of TestRNG falls within ISectRNG  
End If
```

Comment: Intersect wont work in this case, I have tried it. Say I need it to be a range within B2:H8, if your selection is B1:H8, Intersect is still allowing it. So I had to find another way. Thanks for the explanation though.